# How to uninstall Photoshop cs6 trial?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs6

I have tried photoshop cs6 trial on my x64 bit computer. now I want to uninstall photoshop from my computer.

I have go to add or remove software and try to uninstall photoshop. a confirm window open and when I click ok photoshop is removed from list.

but I still have photoshop in my computer (in both program files x86,x64 folder).Someone let me know what is the process to uninstall it.

Comment: What is your OS? I'm gonna guess Windows 7...

Comment: Does it run when you click on it?

Comment: yes it is windows 7

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [CC Cleaner Tool](http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/cs5-cleaner-tool-installation-problems.html) provided by Adobe, it worked as a charm for me to remove CS6.

Answer (score 1):

If you have UAC on that can be the cause of your problem.

Comment: no I am admin on my computer. I have nor allow my computer for guest addition.From forum it's look like manually delete are not good. Is their anyway to detect installation I have and make them uninstall.

Comment: Have you tried looking for an uninstaller in the photoshop directory? If you find one just try running that.

Comment: @AnkitGupta: Being a local admin doesn't mean that uninstaller has been run with elevated permissions thus some things may still fail to execute. These are two different things. And it's always wise to restart machine before uninstalling in case something keeps file/folder handles...

Answer (score 0):

at the bottom right of your screen the adobe cc icon should be there and if you click it and then go to apps once the adobe pop-up comes up you should be able to go and find each program, click the down arrow and then manage and an uninstall option should be there for you to choose.